# trying to put an ajax request inside the success call back of another ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make two jQuery ajax calls, the second should be made from the success callback of the first. I have tried a couple variations of code e.g just messing with the brackets.

Here is what I tried.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'inc/grab_talk.php?name='+encoded_name+'&loc='+encoded_address+'&lat='+encoded_lat,
    type: 'post',
    success: function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/talk_results.php',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (dat) {
                alert(dat);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

I am receiving '500 (internal server error) in console

Comment: your code looks syntactically correct to me. I pasted it in http://jsbeautifier.org/ for re-indenting though. All brackets are closed properly. Can you check your console and share the error here.

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: That means that there is an error on your web server. Your client code is executing fine. If you want to handle an error coming back from your web server, then pass in an `error` function into your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: its strange cause all i have on the talk_results page is 

<?php
echo 'test';
?>

Comment: there is something wrong in your ajax request, are you sure you want to `'inc/grab_talk.php?name=' + encoded_name + '&loc=' + encoded_address + '&lat=' + encoded_lat` in your url. Also check if you are using `POST` on server side or not. Add error callback functions to these requests and display the message in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you can use either POST or GET, but in your case GET seems to be more appropriate.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "somename", location: "somelocation" },
  success: function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "someother.php",
        success: function(){
            alert('test');
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post the code that you have in your server?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax/example.php",
        data: 'page='+btn_page,
        success: function(data){
            $.ajax({
                var a=data; //edit data here
                type: "post",
                url: "example.php",
                data: 'page='+a,
                success: function(data){

});
});
```